# Sorting array/sub document in mongodb PHP based on datetime

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, sorting

I am stuck at a point where i need to sort the documents based on the date time field following is my database structure

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("59199bbb05b505777d86e9a2"),
    "Email" : "sk.sagarkhan95@gmail.com",
    "BlogPosts" : [
            {
                    "PostID" : 7,
                    "Title" : "Party Time",
                    "Name" : "Sagar Khan",
                    "Description" : "Farewell party with 2k17 batchmates at atmosphere 4... #AllNight #Fun #CHEERS....",
                    "Date" : ISODate("2017-05-15T13:18:01Z"),
                    "Image" : "users/sk.sagarkhan95@gmail.com/pictures/prof-pic.jpg",
                    "Likes" : [
                            "hs@gmail.com",
                            "shweta@gmail.com",
                            "ankita@gmail.com",
                            "sk.sagarkhan95@gmail.com"
                    ],
                    "Comments" : [
                            {
                                    "CommentID" : 4,
                                    "email" : "hs@gmail.com",
                                    "Name" : "Harish Shinde",
                                    "Image" : "users/hs@gmail.com/pictures/prof-pic.jpg",
                                    "comment" : "Yo... Cheers ",
                                    "Time" : ISODate("2017-05-15T13:18:40Z")
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59450ce02aa01e3027df57be"),
        "Email" : "hs@gmail.com",
        "BlogPosts" : [
                {
                        "PostID" : 2,
                        "Title" : "At Goa",
                        "Name" : "Harish Shinde",
                        "Description" : "Relaxing at baga Beach Goa ",
                        "Date" : ISODate("2017-06-17T11:05:20Z"),
                        "Image" : "users/hs@gmail.com/pictures/prof-pic.jpg",
                        "Likes" : [
                                "sk.sagarkhan95@gmail.com"
                        ],
                        "Comments" : [ ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Now i want to sort the documents in descending order based on **Date** in the BlogPosts array.
In Mongodb Console i tried

```
db.Timeline.find().sort({BlogPosts.Date : -1 }).pretty()
```

But In PHP i am not able to do this
I tried

```
$cursor = $collection->find()->sort(array("BlogPosts"=>array("Date"=> -1)));
```

and

```
 $cursor = $collection->find()->sort(array("BlogPosts.$.Date"=> -1 ));
```

I also tried the solution mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147845/how-does-sorting-work-in-the-new-mongodb-pecl-extension/35157963#35157963) but no luck... Please help me out

Comment: Use the same ["Dot Notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) form as in the shell. That part is not PHP specific: `$cursor = $collection->find()->sort(array("BlogPosts.Date"=> -1));`

Comment: Thanku soo much that worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
sort(array("BlogPosts.$.Date"=> -1 ));
```

try

```
sort(array("BlogPosts.Date"=> -1 ));
```

[Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731166/mongodb-and-sorting-sub-array)

Comment: Thanku soo much that worked...

Comment: Sounds great !!